# $v_0 is null : What's the fix 

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, slider, slideshow

Firebug gives the above error. I have no idea where to I should look for the fix. $v_0 is null
[Break On This Error] var $v_1 = $v_0.parentElement(); I dont see this line in the code below. Please suggest. (The static code I posted http://www.codeupload.com/4063 here works)

I dont want negative point but I have no choice but to put the whole code.

```
<center>
<div id="BackgroundFrame">  
    <div id="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">  </div>        
        <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="_layouts/jquery/arrow-prev.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"><img src="_layouts/jquery/arrow-next.png" width="24" height="43" alt="Arrow Next"></a>
    </div>
    <img src="_layouts/jquery/example-frame.png" width="739" height="341" alt="Example Frame" id="frame">
</div>      
</center>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_layouts/jquery/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/jquery/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#slides').slides({
                preload: true,
                preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
                play: 5000,
                pause: 2500,
                hoverPause: true,
                animationStart: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:-50
                    },100);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationStart on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                animationComplete: function(current){
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                    if (window.console && console.log) {
                        // example return of current slide number
                        console.log('animationComplete on slide: ', current);
                    };
                },
                slidesLoaded: function() {
                    $('.caption').animate({
                        bottom:0
                    },200);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<script>
  function GetAllImages()
    {
       $("#slideshowPicturePlaceholder").css("display", "block");
       var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>";
       soapEnv += "<listName>News with Pictures</listName>";
       soapEnv += "<query><Query><Where><Eq> <FieldRef Name='Active'/> <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value> </Eq> </Where><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></query>";
       soapEnv += "<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ows_FileLeafRef'/><FieldRef Name='NewsLink'/></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit>";      
       soapEnv += "</GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       var webservice = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

       $.ajax(
       {
          url : webservice,
          type : "POST",
          dataType : "xml",
          data : soapEnv,
          complete : processQueryResults,
          contentType : "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          error : function (xhr)
          {
             alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status);
          }
       });   
    }
    function processQueryResults(xData, status)
    {
       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       // Change the below to point to your image library
       var imageURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/";
       var itemURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=";

       $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function ()
       {
          var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
          var imageLink = imageURL + $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").substring($(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").indexOf('#') + 1);
          var itemLink = $(this).attr("ows_NewsLink");
          var liHtml = "<div class='slide'><a href='"+itemLink+"' target='_blank' border='0'><img width='420' height='220'  src='" + imageLink +"'/></a>" + "<div class='caption' style=\"bottom:'0'\"><p>" + title + "</p></div></div>";
        $("#slides_container").append(liHtml);
        });

    }             
GetAllImages();

</script>
```

Comment: The variable named `$v_0` appears nowhere in the code you posted. What file does the console say the error occurs in? My guess: `slides.min.jquery.js`.

Comment: i think that is jquery conflict issue.

Comment: I am getting this with sharePoint...

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with jquery - the source of the error is sp.ui.rte.debug.js and this error occurs even when jquery is not loaded.

Comment: That error refers to `var $v_1 = $v_0.parentElement();` in sp.ui.rte.debug.js in case anyone happens upon this question now.

Answer (score 1):

Check the plugins. That might be the source of your issue.

Comment: You mean the java library? It works when I hardcode image, links and caption.

Comment: @Amitabh no, he means `slides.min.jquery.js` and any other jQuery plugins that might be present on the page.